# How to check if String is empty in C

Tags: c, string, if-statement, printf

I have a void function which take the string from a global variable and prints them.

The problem is that the void function prints a message/does stuff even if the string is empy. 
so if the global variable is empt it just prints "message is:"
i only want to do something if the string has characters.

what i want to do is to check if the string is not empty, then print a message.

```
// global variable

char msg[30];
scanf("%s", &msg);

void timer(void) {
    //i want to only print if there is a message
    printf("message: %s", msg);
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @juanchopanza are we sure that strln wouldn't return 30 here ?

Comment: @4rlekin Then the string wouldn't be empty. I am assuming a valud null-terminated string. Otherwise the problem is a different one.

Comment: @juanchopanza i meant that provided that scanf() didn't worked uninitialized array would contain 30 * sizeof(char) bytes of garbage AFAIK  Also return from scanf() idicates failure/success

Comment: @4rlekin Right, one should always check the return value of `scanf`. That's a different matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if C string is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485179/how-to-check-if-c-string-is-empty)

Comment: this line: char msg[30]; should be: char msg[30] = {0}; so a known initial is set

Comment: when ever using scanf() the return code should always be checked to assure that something was actually input and the parameters are all set.

Comment: you could change this line: printf("message: %s", msg); to: if( msg && msg[0]) {printf("message: %s", msg);}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easy way to do it would be like this:

```
if (msg[0])
    printf("message: %s", msg);
```

If, at some later date, `msg` is a pointer, you would first want to assure it's not a NULL pointer.

```
if (msg && msg[0])
    printf("message: %s", msg);
```

A test program to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *msg;

void test() {
    if (msg && msg[0])
        printf("string is %s\n", msg);
}

int main()
{
    msg = NULL;
    test();
    msg = calloc(10, 1);
    test();
    msg[0] = 'm';
    msg[1] = 'e';
    test();
    free(msg);
}
```

On my machine the output is:

> string is me

Comment: I think there is no difference between `msg && msg[0]` and `msg[0]` ??

Comment: If it's defined as `char *msg` the difference is that `msg[0]` refers to the first character and `msg` refers to the pointer itself.

Comment: You can always write `msg` as `msg[0]` because it will treated as `*(msg+0)` which is exactly the same as `msg`. Array name is just a constant pointer .So how it make difference, here

Comment: @AmitSharma no. `msg` evaluates to the address of the first `char`. `msg[0]` is the same as `*(msg+0)` but **not** `msg`.  `msg && msg[0]` is true when the pointer is: not null. references a `char` with a non-zero value.  It also short-circits, so it won't try to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: @AmitSharma: I've added a silly little test program to the answer.  Try it.

Answer (score 11):

Strings in C are represented as character arrays, terminated by a character whose value is zero (often written as `'\0'`). The length of a string is the number of characters that come before the zero.

So, a string is empty if the first character in the array is zero, since then by definition *no* characters came before the zero.

This can be checked like so:

```
if(msg[0] != '\0')
{
  /* string isn't empty! */
}
```

This is very explicit code, the shorter `if(msg[0])` or `if(*msg)` has the exact same semantics but can be slightly harder to read. It's mostly a matter of personal style.

Note though that in your case, when you use `scanf()` to read into `msg`, you should check the *return value*  from `scanf()` before checking the contents of `msg`. It's perfectly possible for `scanf()` to fail, and then you can't rely on `msg` being set to an empty string.

Comment: +1 for mentioning return of scanf(). (nobody else saw that as an issue.)

Comment: @ryyker Nobody *ever* does, around here.

Comment: One could also note that the use of a global variable is probably not a good idea either.  Seemed orthogonal to the question asked, though, so I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: @Edward - true especially for embedded, but outside of embedded, there are places where globals are useful.  eg. `extern` scoped struct arrays provide simplicity, and the cost is very affordable when memory is so cheap. (for applications running on a desktop, for example)

Comment: @ryyker: While there may well be instances where a global variable is needed, this is certainly not one of them.

Comment: @Edward - In my previous comment, I was careful to use the phrase _are useful_.  In my experience, globals are rarely _needed_, just expedient.  And again, Absent of a specification, it would be hard to ague against using one here.  Saying _don't ever use globals_ is similar to saying _don't ever cast the output of malloc or calloc._  Most of the time the advice is right on, but other time, its just fine to cast, or use a global.  (in the case of casting malloc/calloc, some C implementations require the cast.)

Comment: @ryyker What C implementations would that be? Very old ones?

Comment: @unwind - Some old ones, yes.  And for people using a C++ compiler wanting to write code portable to C.  But you know all that better than most.  (And yeah, I know, I was not specific in that example, and I said C..., give me a break :)  The main point was that asserting dogmas where the standard doesn't is short sighted, and at best conveys an idea that is not often generally applicable.  Blanket statements should be rarely be made _about when and when not to use globals_.  Very small embedded projects, okay, don't use globals.  In a Windows, desktop application, use all you want.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

The Message will only be printed if it's longer then 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void timer() {

    char msg[30];
    scanf(" %s", msg);

    if(strlen(msg) != 0)
        printf("message: %s", msg);
}

int main() {

    timer();

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This will give error. You have to include`#include<string.h>`.

Comment: I wonder why no one recommends checking the return value of `scanf`? If it fails, the `msg` array may still contain garbage, and the string length is not necessarily 0.

Comment: Dosen't the `&` need to be removed from `scanf`?

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the ways I found (and can think of) to check if a string is empty. Sorted by efficiency.

- `msg[0] == '\0'`
- `strlen(msg) == 0`
- `!strcmp(msg, "")`

And this, which should only happen if the user somehow avoided input (e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>) or there was an error

- `scanf("%s", &msg) <= 0`

Answer (score 0):

I think a quick and easy solution is to use `strlen()` in `string.h` to check the length of the string. if 0 then it is empty.

For example

```
// Check string is NOT empty.
if (strlen(current_word) > 0)
            {
                printf("%s %lu", current_word, strlen(current_word));
                strcpy(current_word, "");
                print_line();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Strlen() function.
2. Comparing with NULL string using strcmp();
3. Checking first character is equal to '\0'.
4. If string is inputted using scanf then check for return value of scanf() function

1st method:

`char msg[30];`

`scanf("%s", &msg);`

`void timer(void) {`

`if(strlen(msg)>0)`

`printf("message: %s", msg);`

`}`

2nd method:

`char msg[30];`

`scanf("%s", &msg);`

`void timer(void) {`

`if(strcmp(msg,"")!=0)`

`printf("message: %s", msg);`

`}`

3rd method:

`char msg[30];`

`scanf("%s", &msg);`

`void timer(void) {`

`if(msg[0]!='\0')`

`printf("message: %s", msg);`

`}`

4th method:

`char msg[30];`

`int rv=scanf("%s", &msg);`

`void timer(void) {`

`if(rv>0)`

`printf("message: %s", msg);`

`}`

For your reference about c string

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strings-in-c-2/

https://scholarsoul.com/string-in-c/

https://www.guru99.com/c-strings.html

Answer (score -1):

Ok,you can try this:

```
char msg[30];
scanf("%s",&msg);

void timer(void)
{
    //i want to only print if there is a message
    if(!msg.length == 0 )
        printf("message: %s", msg);
}
```

`